Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenContentWrapper" was not found in the UIManager
I was searching for 3 days for a solution but I did not find anything yet!

NOTE:
I used expo-cli and physical device (Expo Go), and javascript

I tried all these solutions

npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
npx expo install react-native-screens
npx expo install react-native-screens@lastet

the problem
I feel so tired and I hope someone can help me!

If everything is installed by NPM, do the following in your terminal
For iOS

cd ios && pod install && cd ..

This will install all dependencies into the ios folder. Then go to your .xcworkspace file and build a new application on your iOS emulator / device.
For Android

eas build --profile development --platform android

This is going to create a .APK file for you so you can download it and place it on your emulator / device.

shell complains 'no such command found: eas'

@Naman_DT98 - Execute the following command npm install -g eas-cli 

run npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
FOR IOS
eas build --profile development --platform ios

FOR ANDROID
eas build --profile development --platform android

